# Conditional Parent opening Div in React JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a case like this, In handlebars, we can conditionally render just the parent opening div, now, I am moving to React so got the below issue.

```
const ProductBlock: FC<Props> = (props: Props): JSX.Element => (
   <div className="image">
      // render the opening div conditionally
      {
       props.showImage ? 
       (
         <div className="show-review-image">
       )
       :
       (
         <div className="show-old-image">
       )
      }
      // this div will be the child of the above resulting conditional div
      <div className="child-div">
        <ul className="inline-list">
          {
            props.myArr.map((attribute: authorAttribute, index: number): JSX.Element => (
              <li key={index}>
                {attribute.key} {attribute.value}
              </li>
            ))
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
);
```

while doing so, i am getting the error
`JSX element 'div' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)`

My question is, Is it possible to do like above ?

Comment: Let me recorrect the code

Comment: I get it now. This was really trivial. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone already pointed out, you need braces around `props.showImage ?` to get it to be JS and not just a string in HTML. This is causing both of your `div`s to be treated as opening tags that require closing.

However, there's a deeper problem. Your ternary operator can't work the way you want it to. Both options must be complete expressions, not partial *beginnings* of expressions. `<div className="show-review-image">` is not a complete expression. `<div className="show-review-image></div>` is. So both paths in your conditional expression must have closing tags for any tags they open.

That said, the solution is simple. Put the ternary expression inside the class name itself: `<div className={ props.showImage ? "show-review-image" : "show-old-image" } >`